# Convert a region of a JPanel into a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I need to convert a certain region of an jpanel into a bufferedImage, or other format to be shown in another jpanel.

By now, I only saw codes that converts the whole jpanel into a bufferedImage, but in my case, I need just an area inside an jpanel.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a BufferedImage with the requested size to receive the image.
Get a Graphics2D for drawing on this image and let the JPanel paint on it.

```
    JPanel panel = ...
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 200, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gg = image.createGraphics();
    try {
        gg.translate(-100, -20);  // start point of region negated
        panel.paint(gg);
    } finally {
        gg.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You may find you need to use printAll(Graphics) rather than paint(Graphics). I think that is the recommended method for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have code to convert the entire thing to a `BufferedImage`, you can use that, then call [`getSubImage`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on the resulting `BufferedImage` to get a subregion.

Answer (score 1):

> *By now, I only saw codes that converts the whole jpanel into a bufferedImage, but in my case, I need just an area inside an jpanel.*

Then take that image and repaint the desired area into a new image and you're done.

Comment: Oscar - where did you spend all your reputation?? Bounty? ^^

Comment: Every time I reach 10K I reborn :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be [Robot.createScreenCapture()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle))

You'll need to translate from the panel's coordinate system to the screen coordinate system. See [Component.getBounds()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds()) and [Component.getLocationOnScreen()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()).

Comment: the link you referenced seems to be local, you might want to update that before someone downvotes you for an innocent mistake.